# Setting the variable with the form and return to the initial value after some time

Tags: python, django

I have created an app using Django, I have a variable that I set using a form for more security. But after a few hours, I check its value and see that it is zero. Every time I set the value, after a while the value becomes zero
I have published this app on the host

view.py

```
w_m = "xxx"
def admin_setbasedata(request):
    form_ = admin_form()
    global w_m
        if request.method == "POST" and "set_w" in request.POST:
            w_m=request.POST.get('serial')
```

form.py

```
class admin_form(forms.Form):
     serial = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-input','oninput':'w_t(this)', 'id': 'serial','autocomplete':"off"}),)
```

I make variable w_m equal to "YYY" using the form.

I check the values and it is "YYY".

I check again after an hour and it is equal to "xxx".

It seems that every time the site is visited, view.py is executed from the beginning and the variables are reset to their initial values.

Comment: Example?, view? forms.py? traceback? your questions doesn't help much.

Comment: You haven't given much to go on here, and I have never even seen Django code, but if I understand correctly; the server holds this variable? I would put a [closure](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure) on the variable and log how it changes, or set a one way flag that will raise an error when a second write is attempted

Comment: @Martins Question updated

Comment: Can you edit header fields in Django? If the goal is to replicate the error as minimally as possible, I would try to make Django server close the connection to see if the thread, socket, asyncio, whatever, closes and the variable gets garbage collected instead of staying alive as you check on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to import the variables from the file and record the changes in the file

```
w_m = "YYYY"
with open('myvar.py', 'w') as file:
     file.write("w_m = " + w_m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a user goes to your page, views.py will be run, and `w_m` will be set to `"xxx"`.  So when you say,

> It seems that every time the site is visited, view.py is executed from
> the beginning and the variables are reset to their initial values.

That is what is *supposed* to happen.  If you need to have a variable that is maintained like what I believe you are trying to do with the `global` identifier, you need to put that into your database.